# How to detect a newLine when there is only Carriage Return [13] without a LF aside

Tags: java, swing

**QUESTION EDITED**

In my Java program my barcode reader reads some characters into a TextBox.
This string ends with `[CR]` char. In my listener I get `KeyCode 77` **M** char for a `[CR]` but for `[LF]` I get `10` as expected.

**How can I handle a newline to trigger enter operation when I get only `[CR]` without a `[LF]` and what is this 77 (M) ?**

This is what I expect

[image]

This is what I get. **CR** is **ASCII 13** but I get **77** (M char)

[image]

Normally in my barcode there is an actual M char and I don't want to handle 77 as enter.

My string ends with only `CR` but not `LF` . I think in Windows CR+LF makes a newline. My problem is without `LF` I can't handle `CR`. So I can't handle an `enter`.

Which component or listener should I use to handle just CR (decimal 13)? In a `.NET` app I can easily handle this`[CR]`.

Here is my listener

```
textFieldSquareBarcode.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   
               if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER || e.getKeyCode()=='\r')
                DO(); //!!!!
             }
```

P.S.

CR is Carriage Return 13 decimal '\n' 0x0D hex

LF is Line Feed 10 decimal '\r' 0x0A hex

**EDIT:**
As you see below '\r' and '\n' are recognized characters. But when barcode printer reads `[CR]` I can't see it in my keyListener event. Can you comment here if something is still unclear ?

```
    char LF='\r';   
    char CR='\n';
    String whatINeed=CR+""+LF;
    String whatIhave=""+CR;
    String empty="";
    for (char c : whatINeed.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.println((int)c);
    }

output 
10
13
```

**EDIT 2:**

How it works on .Net Framework.

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char c = e.KeyChar;
        textBox2.Text += $"{(int)c} | ({c}) {Environment.NewLine}";
        if ((int)c == 13)
            MessageBox.Show("Enter!!!");
    }
```

Now I'll try to print a `[CR]` character only barcode and diagnose this more accurately.

Comment: Have you tested this?  I'm not sure that it would really matter, if you're getting the `CR` (char `13`) then what else do you care about?  You should note that virtual keys don't (or aren't meant to) map to ASCII characters, so `getKeyCode() == '\r`` is actually meaningless.  Have you tried an `ActionListener`?

Comment: Another choice would be to use a `DocumentFilter` or `DocumentListener`

Comment: You can't handle CR without LF why? NB CR is `\r` and LF is `\n`, not the other way around. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm not getting CR(13) somehow. This is the exact problem.This also doesn't work `e.getKeyCode()==13` .

Comment: @DavutGürbüz `keycode` != `ascii/character code`. I'd imagine you "might" get `e.getKeyChar() == 10` (10 been LF/`/n`)

Comment: So, what is `CR` ? How can I handle this ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer KeyEvent.VK_ENTER is mapped to '\n'. You can see it by going deep into the code.

Comment: ` public static final int VK_ENTER          = '\n';`, from KeyEvent.class

Comment: @DavutGürbüz But you can't rely on it, it's a constant and may change, the "mapping" is more coincidence than anything

Comment: @MadProgrammer same coincidence occurs for `\r` too. See my EDIT. So, my code should work properly in case CR is handled. But KeyListener does not handle it.I'm looking for a workaround and what is wrong with my question. I don't understand

Comment: @DavutGürbüz Without out know exactly the key sequence (or precisely, the characters) which you scanner sends you, it's impossible to know how you might fix it. Personally, I'd avoid `KeyListener` and try some of the others

Comment: @MadProgrammer "it's a constant and may change", this must be some new definition of "constant" i was previously unaware of. Seriously though, it can't change without breaking old programs which the Java Platform does not do.

Comment: Anyway. Thanks for contributing my issue. I've solved this. Just `CR` is handled as `77` in this listener. This is `M` in ASCII. I check if CTRL key is pressed at the same time. It behaves a little different than `.NET`. You can just check if charcode is 13 or not in C#.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström The value of the constant can change, that's the point of using the constant "name" and not it's value

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström For example, the OP is using `e.getKeyCode()==77` in there answer, which is mapped to `VK_M`, what happens if the values are changed and `77` is changed to `VK_Z`?  Everybody using `VK_M` don't blink and the OP's code explodes in there face, that's what I'm talking about

Comment: @MadProgrammer: No, it literally can't change. If you decompile a class using an integer constant, you will see that the name wasn't compiled in, but the actual value.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Oh, it can change, the fact that you might need to recompile the code aside, one should rely on the constant name, not it's value is the point

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Of course it's technically possible to edit the source and recompile and distribute a new version, and try to force everyone to recompile their old code with the new version. But no one will ever do that because everything would break. So it will never happen. Thus constants are constants, and values of constants do not ever change.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Oh, I think we're just to use to Java's "backwards" compatibility focus, because it does happen in other languages and you know what, people deal with it ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer But we *are* talking about Java, and you can rely on the constants not changing.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström I still think you're relying in Java's backwards compatiability focus. What happens when Java 2.0 is released? Can you guarantee that it won't draw a line in the sand on backwards compatibility? A simple recompile would be much easier then trying to track down all the places a constant name SHOULD have been used. The point is, rely on the constant name, not the "expected" value

Comment: @MadProgrammer: There will never be a Java 2.0. They're leaving that version numbering scheme, the next version will be Java 9, not 1.9.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Today, there will never be a version 2.0, tomorrow, who knows, things change ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: You're just building a straw man so you don't have to admit you're wrong. As they say in Canada: Peace, i'm oot.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Assuming nothing will change is a course for disaster. Relying on the constant names (and assuming everything else will change) is good programming practice, unless you suggest we should just change the code to remove the constant names and rely on the values, because they'll never change, because that could never possibly go wrong. My point is still, rely on the known, not the assumed. Change is the only constant in the universe. Today, you're right, tomorrow, who knows, at least I'd only need to re-compile my code if it did

Comment: Dear folks in my very personal opinion if Carriage Return ASCII key code changes one day. Yes , right it's crucial to use constant name instead of value. But, I do not believe that this will change one day or my program will be in use that day :). We prefer enum variables for these kind of variable attributes in our software.We rely on constants and their values and use their names just for readability. BTW, Can you review my question ? It's still put on hold for being unclear.

Answer (score 2):

> Char 13=CR is handled as `CTRL pressed + M` in Java KeyListener event.
>   You can test this by pressing CTRL+M in notepad++.

This is the solution for handling **just Carriage Return**. Hope helps one else.

```
if(e.isControlDown()&&e.getKeyCode()==77)
```

ASCII Control Codes in Code 128 Barcodes
Home > Barcode Basics > Application Notes > AppNote022

Code 128 barcodes can include ASCII control codes as well as all the standard printable ASCII characters. A keyboard wedge scanner will read a barcode and transmit characters to the computer just as though they had been typed at the keyboard. The key codes transmitted from the keyboard and the wedge scanner are in a format particular to the PC architecture; they are not standard ASCII codes. Every standard ASCII character has an equivalent key code, and the keyboard wedge scanner automatically performs the conversion and sends the appropriate key code.
However, virtually all keyboards include many keys for which there are no ASCII equivalents: the F1 through F12 function keys, for example. These key codes can be sent from the keyboard to the computer, but there is no equivalent ASCII character that can be printed in a Code 128 barcode.

Many keyboard wedge scanners can be configured replace a specific barcode character with a different keyboard code. Since the keyboard wedge scanner transmits key codes to the computer, it can send any keyboard character. For example, a scanner could be configured to FS code (ASCII decimal 28) to an F10 key.

Here is a list of ASCII control codes. The first column lists the equivalent CTRL+key codes (^ used to indicate holding down the CTRL key):

Key ASCII
Function

```
^2  00  NUL null
^A  01  SOH start of header
^B  02  STX start transmission
^C  03  ETX end transmission
^D  04  EOT end of tape
^E  05  ENQ enquiry
^F  06  ACK acknowledge
^G  07  BEL bell
^H  08  BS backspace
^I  09  HT horizontal tab
^J  10  LF line feed
^K  11  VT vertical tab
^L  12  FF form feed
^M  13  CR carriage return
^N  14  SO shift out
^O  15  SI shift in
^P  16  DLE data link enable
^Q  17  DC1 device control 1
^R  18  DC2 device control 2
^S  19  DC3 device control 3
^T  20  DC4 device control 4
^U  21  NAK negative acknowledge
^V  22  SYN sync
^W  23  ETB
^X  24  CAN cancel
^Y      25  EM
^Z  26  SUB substitute
^[  27  ESC escape
^\  28  FS field separator
^]  29  GS group separator
^6  30  RS record separator
^-  31  US
```

After this comes the space bar (32) followed by the normal printable characters.

http://www.makebarcode.com/info/appnote/app_022.html

Here is the complete code, instead of `KeyAdapter` I used `KeyListener` implementation and wrote my code under `KeyPressed` not `KeyRelased` to handle Ctrl is down.

```
      textFieldSquareBarcode.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {                        
                if (e.getKeyCode()==77&&e.isControlDown()) {
                    //DO_IT(); !!!
                    };                                      
        }}
    );
```